Excel nested header mapping using Python
I have an Excel file with a nested header:

And after reading the header content ends up with:
header = [
    ['Order', 'Translation', '', '', '', '', 'Status', ''], 
    ['', 'Not available', 'Language', '', '', '', 'Packed', 'Delivered'], 
    ['', '', 'English', '', 'FR', 'ES', '', ''], 
    ['', '', 'US', 'UK', '', '', '', '']
]

Now I want to obtain something like this:

output = [
'Order',
'Translation.Not Available',
'Translation.Language.English.US',
'Translation.Language.English.UK',
'Translation.Language.FR',
'Translation.Language.ES',
'Status.Packed',
'Status.Delivered'
]

Any idea how this output can be achieved? Can be also in the JSON format. Thanks!
{
    "Order": "",
    "Translation": {
        "Not Available": "",
        "Language": {
            "English": {
                "US": "",
                "UK": ""
            },
            "FR": "",
            "ES": ""
        }
    },
    "Status": {
        "Packed": "",
        "Delivered" : ""
    }
}


Are the larger header fields in merged cells or individual cells?

Hi @PeterT! Larger cells are merged, and reading rows from excel will result in the above "header" variable. I don't know what transformations I need to add in order to get the "output" variable, or a JSON structure like described. Thanks!

The answer is in the structure of the header. From the list, you can tell there are four rows and eight columns. So your code logic must look at the "cell" in the first row (Order) and determine if covers one or more columns (peek forward in the row until you find a non-empty entry). In the case of Order, it covers only one column, so check the first entry of each "row" list to build that item.  That's how you solve this, so put together a Python program and come back if you have questions about the code and/or the errors you may be getting.

Hi again @PeterT! I guess I will need a lot of if/else conditions to achive this. For example the following is needed only to get the first branch: ['Order', 'Translation.Not available', 'Status.Packed']
for i in range(len(header[0])):
for j in range(1, len(header)):
if header[0][i]:
main_label = header[0][i]
if main_label and header[0][j]:
sub_label = header[j][i]
if sub_label:
output.append(f'{main_label}.{sub_label}')
else:
output.append(main_label)

That's a very good start! Add to your logic to count the number of blank entries following each item in the first row (Order blanks=0, Translation blanks=4, etc.). That's what you'll use to increment down and over in the bottom three rows. Some advanced Python folks may jump in with a recursion function (a function that calls itself). That would be fine, but don't worry about it for now. You're working out the logic very well so far. Keep going.
